# Pandas dataframe grouping values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like this,

```
dd = pd.DataFrame(
{'name': ['abc','bcd','abc'],
 'seconds': [75,77,90],
})
```

[image]

I need to combine the seconds column into a single list for rows with same name.

I am able to do this using for loop,

```
names= list(set(dd['name']))
counter=[]
for a in names:
    counter.append(list(dd[dd['name'] == a]['seconds']))
end
seconds_list = pd.DataFrame(
{'name': names,
'seconds': counter,
})
```

Output:

[image]

But this takes a lot of time on a big dataframe. Any simple way to achieve this without a for loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `list`:

```
df = dd.groupby('name')['seconds'].apply(list).reset_index()
print (df)

  name   seconds
0  abc  [75, 90]
1  bcd      [77]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby`, `agg`, and  `tolist`:

```
 dd.groupby('name')['seconds'].agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index(name='seconds')
```

Output:

```
  name   seconds
0  abc  [75, 90]
1  bcd      [77]
```